# Inconsistent trailing slash in DOCUMENT_ROOT variable in PHP when using Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, php, configuration, documentroot

In different server environments, the PHP `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` super global sometimes has a trailing slash and sometimes it does not. I would have thought this issue is directly related to how the Apache `DocumentRoot` is defined in the `httpd.conf` file:

i.e. I would have thought that if `httpd.conf` contains no trailing slash:

```
<VirtualHost *:8880>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/live/current
    ...
```

then `echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` should give */var/www/live/current*

and if `httpd.conf` does contain a trailing slash:

```
<VirtualHost *:8880>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/live/current/
    ...
```

then `echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` should give */var/www/live/current/*

This is the case on Ubuntu 10.04 but on RHEL 5.5 a trailing slash is added to `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` even if none was defined on Apache.

Any idea why this happens? Is there a configuration parameter that I'm missing?

---

For reference:

- PHP 5.3.3 of RHEL (issue occurs): *PHP 5.3.3 (cli) (built: Jul 23 2010 16:26:53)*
- PHP version of Ubuntu (no issue): *PHP 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.2 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: May 13 2010 20:03:45)*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have no idea why the slash is changing between your virtual hosts. By the way, is it important ? Just add a new slash to your programs (remove if a double slash is present) and the problem is solved.

I use

```
$realpath = realpath ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/");
$realpath = str_replace ("//", "/", $realpath);
```

Comment: You could simply use ``$realpath = realpath($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);``. It automatically removes all multiple slashes and also the trailing one. If you always want a trailing slash concatenate it to the result of the above call to ``realpath()``. Not inside it.

Comment: I can confirm the same issue (php 5.5) between a Hosteurope host (Ubuntu I think): has slash... and Windows 7: no slash  (fairly recent XAMPP install)

Comment: `rtrim($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'],'/\\').'/'` should be slightly faster than all those things realpath can do.

Answer (score 3):

Document root in an Apache environment can be defined in more than one place.

Yes, `httpd.conf` contains these settings, but they can be overwritten as this file is used for the default configuration.

I'd suggest you go check the vhost configuration under `vhosts.d` and `sites-available` directories.

Answer (score 3):

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html says: The DocumentRoot should be specified without a trailing slash.

Answer (score 2):

The proposed solution:

```
$realpath = realpath ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/");
$realpath = str_replace ("//", "/", $realpath);
```

does not work in all of the installations.

For example, in my case:

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']  = "/www/site/"
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/" = "/www/site//"
realpath("/www/site//") = "/www/site"
str_replace("//", "/", "/www/site") = "/www/site"
```

Same problem as before.

May be you should modify the first instruction in:

```
$realpath = realpath ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'])."/";
```

thistle

Comment: `rtrim($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'],'/\\').'/'` should be slightly faster than all those things realpath can do.

Answer (score 2):

Dom's answer is a solution to this issue, however stefanvesca's statement is the reason why in the different environments you are experiencing the double '//'. On your local machine, within your .conf file where you set up your virtual host, you most likely added the / at the end of the defined document root, while the person who set up your other environment did not, or vice versa.

Eitherway, when using php's $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] you get the apache environment value which is the result of the configuration. That is the reason for the '/' in one environment and '//' in another.

Answer (score 1):

I would say it's assumed DOCUMENT_ROOT has no trailing slash.

This value is passed from the web server configuration

apache

`DocumentRoot /var/www/html`

That implies we should have a leading slash to path we add to it.

Knowing that a double slash '//' anywhere in the path has no consequence (when related to filesystem... in a http url, there could be cases where is has some glitches)

`$ cat /etc//issue
Debian GNU/Linux 9 \n \l`

When there is a trailing slash to DOCUMENT_ROOT we can blame sysadmin on something that has no consequence :)

And safely ignore it?